# How can I get a users IP Address for Wordpress in phpMyAdmin or IP address of phpMyAdmin log in records?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, logging, phpmyadmin, ip

I believe my MySQL database was compromised by a former disgruntled developer who had access to the DB. They created some super admin user accounts for wordpress and also messed with some other things. Is there a way to find the IP address of remotely logged in MySQL users or some way to view an activity log that has timestamp and IP address? Please, some detailed help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check 'general query log' if enabled

Comment: There are plenty of plugins that will keep user activity logs. A quick google search turned up this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-login-log/